# dedicated web server for my application/s?

Tags: dedicated-hosting

I am looking for a dedicated server because shared webhosting solutions have some limitations.

I am going to start with one appliation (web server + db) but in the future I will need more resources for more applications. I am starting small so the price is very important right now the quality is more important though.

The requirements are like (not sure what I forgot)

- scalable hw resources (memory, hdd, bandwith)
- linux/unix based
- able to install programs
- ssh
- ssl/https
- backup solution?
- unlimited number of outgoing emails
- 'simple scripts' ?
- server user management

### Update

Does the location of the server matters as I want to target my 'visitors' world wide?

Comment: I wonder why somebody wants to close this question...

Comment: is maybe more of a server fault question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't know where you are from and if it matters to you where the server's at. But I am very happy with swiss based hostfactory (I host some ecommerce solutions there). The support team reacts very fast and you'll get full control of the server (rdp access on windows, shell access on linux).

Check it out here: [hostfactory](http://www.hostfactory.ch/de/virtual_server/vps.html)

Hardware resources are scalable via the web interface.

Comment: thank you I'll have a look. You brought up an interesting question:"Does the location of the server matters?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes - location matters. If you are going with just one server location, you need to make your best guess as to where most of your visitors are going to come from.

The plumbing of the internet tends to be US centric, so if you are not sure, and have no legal restrictions on where your data can live, that may be your best (and often cheapest) option.

Comment: any recommendations for any US based hosting provider?

Comment: There are quite a few, not much personal experience in US, as I work in AU, and often have legal restrictions on data locations, but Rackspace look good from a dollars for features basis, especially compared to here in AU.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how the response time of, say a request for an image, differs depending on the location of the server. Has anyone got a link to a benchmark?

Speaking of legal restrictions, that would be a reason to not locate a server within the US. :-)

Comment: I'm in AU too :-) what legal restrictions are you talking about if you can elaborate on that...

Comment: It depends on who you are selling to. If you sell services to govt or corporates, they often have restrictions on where data can be stored. I read a while ago that France was introducing laws about any data regarding their citizens having to be stored in France - even for sites like FB - don't know where this has got to. Some clients will have policies as to the transit security of backup tapes...etc... No single answer, but as SaaS grows in popularity, laws/policies about data are on the up world wide - just be aware that it may be a factor for you some day :)

Comment: wow, that's sound sooo complicated. Thank you for that note.Keep it in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I went for [linode](http://www.linode.com)